# How to predict on new data with saved OPTICS clustering model

Tags: python, machine-learning, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

I work with density based clustering and usually cluster on data (text) as and when I get it.

However, I want to save and re-use one of my clustering models since it would reduce memory costs by sending my data sequentially instead of having to dump all of it in memory and cluster on-demand.

I tried to achieve this by pickling my OPTICS clusterer object.

This is how I want to use the model:

```
def load_pickle(pickle_filepath:str):
    model_file = pickle.load(open(pickle_filepath, "rb"))        
    return model_file

class StoredClusterer:

    def __init__(self, dimred_model, clustering_model):

        self.dimred_model = dimred_model
        self.clustering_model = clustering_model

    def predict(self, embedding):

        reduced_embedding = self.dimred_model.transform(embedding)
        approximate_cluster = self.clustering_model.predict(reduced_embedding)

        return approximate_cluster

dimred_model = load_pickle('path/to/pickle/file')
clustering_model = load_pickle('path/to/pickle/file')

clusterer_object = StoredClusterer(dimred_model, clustering_model)
```

I have gone through the documentation for [OPTICS](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.OPTICS.html); but it does not seem to have a 'predict()' like [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) does.

Is there any way to custom build the predict() for OPTICS?
If not, what would be the best solution to remember and predict clusters with density based clustering algorithms?

Since the output of my density based algorithm is a couple hundred very fine grained clusters, it does not make sense to use the output of fit_predict() as training data for a supervised learning algorithm.